# lookup fail safe answer - excel formula I don't get

Tags: arrays, excel, operators

On [this thread : Find last non-zero cell's column reference in an UNORDERED range of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527156/find-last-non-zero-cells-column-reference-in-an-unordered-range-of-values) I found two solutions to my problem. But I couldn't understand the way they work. I'm sure it's documented somewhere online but can't find the keywords.

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:L1<>0),COLUMN(A1:L1))`

What key word should I use to find documents on the result/mechanism of a boolean operator over an array `A1:L1<>0` ?

Used as a array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) Excel happily computes a cell with `= A1:L1<>0` as `= A1<>0`. It returns a boolean value (True=1, False=0). Assuming that boolean is later inverted, the resulting array should be a serie of `1` and `#DIV/0`, yet the `LOOKUP()` searchs for a `2`, as lookup_value, and seem to find it.

Additionally there is this one that does the same thing but witch I won't use because I'm not confident in array formulas `{=MAX(IF(yourrange=0,0,COLUMN(yourrange)))}`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried using the Evaluate button on Excel? that way you can see the calculation step by step and see how it works

Comment: Thanks indeed the step shows the ```1``` and ```#DIV/0``` array. but no ```2``` on the horizon yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is extracted from here, so actually all credits go to author of it:

> [Excel Formula To Get LAST Non-Zero Value in Row and Return Column
>   Header](https://superuser.com/a/937584)

This works because the `1/(E2:CO2<>0)` part returns an array of either 1s where the cell isn't zero......or `#DIV/0!` errors where it is. LOOKUP then **won't find 2 in that array so it matches with the last** 1, i.e. the last column with a non-zero value.....and it then returns the corresponding value from the header row.

> I post it because the question can be marked as duplicate because the
>   answer is not on SO.

**UPDATE:** I want to add some extra info, based on Office Support:

> [LOOKUP
>   Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

And using as example [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527156/find-last-non-zero-cells-column-reference-in-an-unordered-range-of-values)

According to this source:

> *If the LOOKUP function can't find the lookup_value, the function matches the largest value in lookup_vector that is less than or equal
>   to lookup_value.*

When you do the `1/(E2:CO2<>0)` part returns an array (lookup_vector) of either 1s where the cell isn't zero......or `#DIV/0!`, so we get an array like this:

```
#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;1;1;1;1;1;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!
```

So LOOKUP checks each single value in the array from left to right. If nothing is found, it will take the largest one, which is 1.

But because 1 is present in many positions inside array, and last 1 checked is at 8th position, so the formula then goes to the array created by `COLUMN(A1:L1)` (result_vector) which is something like this:

`1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12`

It checks the value at 8th position, which holds the value 8, and then the formula returns the number 8.

Hope this throws some light.

Comment: It throws some light indeed, it seems that even if it finds the desired value, match tends to return the last occurence. So ```=LOOKUP(1,1/(A1:L1<>0),COLUMN(A1:L1))``` works as well as ```=LOOKUP(861,1/(A1:L1<>0),COLUMN(A1:L1))```